# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mate

I was running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS. For some reason, I had to reinstall it. I chose the option to erase the disk and install Ubuntu. After installation the setup asked me to remove installation media and then press enter. I did so. The screen is now blank. Ubuntu won't boot. I need only one OS on my computer, Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS, so no dual boot is required for me.

**Details:**

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/My6DZks5HH/

**More details:**

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/fstab 
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

and

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~/Desktop$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="b2b51a07-462c-4262-992e-827baa57ebb9" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="AFD2-B0DD" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda4: UUID="08b48503-00a3-490e-82c9-b97c01870f3c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="7bbd379b-45f3-4bfa-9c26-17a7c04db3e5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2018-07-25-03-37-28-00" LABEL="Ubuntu-MATE 18.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="0D5F-1DB6" TYPE="vfat"
```

**MBR:**

I do not need any data from my hard drive. I tried to use [efibootmgr](https://sites.google.com/view/fossusersgroup/articles/deleting-efi-boot-entries).

[image]

Comment: How many partitions does your sda have, 2 or 4, your postings are inconsistent.  Check that your UEFI settings select UEFI mode over legacy, your partial legacy boot setup will fail if attempted.

Comment: Whatever the Ubuntu's "erase everything and install ubuntu on the entire disk" option does, on a 2 TB HDD.

Comment: Nothing looks odd other than the leftover grub in MBR.  If you force grub (single OS so hold down shift or tab at boot, or use EFI menu to select ubuntu), try the recovery option (it has nomodeset). Blank screen may be a video problem, do you have Nvidia hardware?